# Show that up to scalar multiple there is a unique intertwining operator $\operatorname{Ind}_B^G(\chi)\to \operatorname{Ind}_N^G(\psi).$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G=GL(2,\mathbb {F}_q)$ and $B=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
* & *  \\
0 & * 
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$ the
Borel subgroup of upper triangular matrices, and let $N$ be its subgroup of unipotent matrices. Let $\psi_q:\mathbb{F}_q\to\mathbb{C}$ be any nontrivial character. Define a character of $N$ as follows:
$$\psi\left(\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x  \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\right)=\psi_q(x).$$
Let $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ be the characters of $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ and consider the character $\chi:B\to\mathbb{C}^\times$ by $$\chi\left(\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 & *  \\
0 & y_2 
\end{pmatrix}\right)=\chi_1(y_1)\chi_2(y_2)\qquad \text{for all $y_1,y_2\in\mathbb{F}_q$ with $y_1y_2\neq 0$}.$$ Show that up to scalar multiple there is a unique intertwining operator $\operatorname{Ind}_B^G(\chi)\to \operatorname{Ind}_N^G(\psi).$

---

The problem is from the chapter Mackey Theory in the textbook, Lie groups by D. Bump. I had the following attempt. But, I'm making a mistake somewhere. Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Attempt**. It is enough to show that $\dim \operatorname{Hom} _G(\operatorname{Ind}_B^G(\chi),\operatorname{Ind}_N^G(\psi))=1$.

Note that $\{1,\omega\}$ is a complete set of representatives of the double cosets in $N\setminus G / B$ where $\omega=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.$ By [Theorem 32.2](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-8024-2_32.pdf), we have

$$\dim \operatorname{Hom} _G(\operatorname{Ind}_B^G(\chi),\operatorname{Ind}_N^G(\psi))=\dim\operatorname{Hom}_{H_{\gamma_1}}(\chi^{\gamma_1},\psi^{\gamma_1})+\dim\operatorname{Hom}_{H_{\gamma_2}}(\chi^{\gamma_2},\psi^{\gamma_2})$$

where $\gamma_1=1, \gamma_2=\omega$ and $H_{\gamma_i}=H_2\cap\gamma_iH_1\gamma_i^{-1}$ for all $i\in\{1,2\},$ $H_1=B, H_2=N$. So, $H_{\gamma_1}=N$ and $H_{\gamma_2}=N\cap\omega B\omega^{-1}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\right\}.$ So, $\dim\operatorname{Hom}_{H_{\gamma_2}}(\chi^{\gamma_2},\psi^{\gamma_2})=0$ since $H_{\gamma_2}$ is the trivial subgroup. So, it remains to show that $\dim\operatorname{Hom}_{H_{\gamma_1}}(\chi^{\gamma_1},\psi^{\gamma_1})=1.$ Note that $\chi^{\gamma_1}:H_{\gamma_1}\to GL(\operatorname{Ind}_B^G(\chi))$ is defined by $\chi^{\gamma_1}(h)=\chi(\gamma_1^{-1}h\gamma_1)$ for $h\in H_{\gamma_1}$. Since  $\gamma_1=1$, we have $\chi^{\gamma_1}=\chi|_N.$ Also, by definition, we have $\psi^{\gamma_1}=\psi |_{H_{\gamma_1}}=\psi |_N=\psi.$ Since $\chi^{\gamma_1}$ and $\psi^{\gamma_1}$ are both one dimensional representations of $N$, we have $\dim\operatorname{Hom}_{H_{\gamma_1}}(\chi^{\gamma_1},\psi^{\gamma_1})\leq 1.$
Pick any $L\in\operatorname{Hom}_{H_{\gamma_1}}(\chi^{\gamma_1},\psi^{\gamma_1})$. Then $L$ is either an isomorphism or the zero map. But, $L$ cannot be an isomorphism otherwise we would have $L\circ \chi^{\gamma_1}=\psi^{\gamma_1}\circ L$ which implies that $\psi: N\to \Bbb C$ is the trivial character, that is, $\psi_q$ is the trivial character,  contradiction. So $L$ must be the zero map. So, $\dim\operatorname{Hom}_{H_{\gamma_1}}(\chi^{\gamma_1},\psi^{\gamma_1})=0.$

Comment: Hint: your general line of argument is good, but at the point where you say "so [something] is the trivial character (which it's not)", it should be that a particular _restriction_ of it is trivial...